# Объединение многомерных массивов

Tags: php, массивы, yii2

Есть массив

```
$arr1[] = array("id"=>"1", "count"=>"0", "otd"=>"south");
$arr1[] = array("id"=>"2", "count"=>"4", "otd"=>"north");
$arr1[] = array("id"=>"3", "count"=>"8", "otd"=>"south");
```

и второй массив:

```
$arr2[] = array("id"=>"1", "count"=>"1", "otd"=>"south");
$arr2[] = array("id"=>"2", "count"=>"3", "otd"=>"north");
$arr2[] = array("id"=>"3", "count"=>"5", "otd"=>"south");
```

У условных пользователей в этом массивe совпадают id, но count разный.
Как можно сделать третий массив результирующий?(Суммируются count)
Я пробовал при помощи array_merge, но второй массив просто дозаписывался в конец

```
arr3[1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [count] => 1   //0+1
            [otd] => south
        )

arr3[2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [count] => 7    //3+4
            [otd] => north
        )

arr3[3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [count] => 13    //5+8
            [otd] => south
        )
```

И вот еще, что интересно.
Если переименую второй ключ в массиве и массивы будут такими:

```
$arr1[] = array("id"=>"1", "count"=>"0", "otd"=>"south");
$arr1[] = array("id"=>"2", "count"=>"4", "otd"=>"north"); 
$arr1[] = array("id"=>"3", "count"=>"8", "otd"=>"south");

$arr2[] = array("id"=>"1", "not_count"=>"1", "otd"=>"south");
$arr2[] = array("id"=>"2", "not_count"=>"3", "otd"=>"north");
$arr2[] = array("id"=>"3", "not_count"=>"5", "otd"=>"south");
```

Как можно получить массив такого вида?

```
 arr3[1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [count] => 0  
                [otd] => south
                [not_count] => 1
            )

arr3[2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [count] => 3   
            [otd] => north
            [not_count] => 4
        )

arr3[3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [count] => 5 
            [otd] => south
            [not_count] => 8
        )
```

Пробовал сделать слияние, но [not_count] записывался поверх [count] первого массива с новым значением

Comment: сделайте вот так $arr = array_column($arr, null, 'id') с обоими массивами, их индексами станут id, дальше дело техники

Comment: как можно добавить ключ (второго массива) [not_count]   со значением к первому массиву или результирующему третьему?
С суммой, кажется, разобрался

Comment: @Pvokinsark $data[]=array('id'=>$value['id'], 'count'=>$value['count'], 'otd'=>$value['otd'], 'not_count'=$value1['not_count']);  и прежде чем на лету менять ход задания, разберись с представленными кодами, тут уже все по полочкам разложили

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$arr1= array(array("id"=>"1", "count"=>"0", "otd"=>"south"),
array("id"=>"2", "count"=>"4", "otd"=>"north"),
array("id"=>"3", "count"=>"8", "otd"=>"south"));
$arr2 = array(array("id"=>"1", "count"=>"1", "otd"=>"south"),
array("id"=>"2", "count"=>"3", "otd"=>"north"),
array("id"=>"3", "count"=>"5", "otd"=>"south"));

foreach ($arr1 as $key => $value) {
    # code...
foreach ($arr2 as $key1 => $value1) {
    # code...
if($value['id']==$value1['id']){
 $data[]=array('id'=>$value['id'], 'count'=>$value['count']+$value1['count'], 'otd'=>$value['otd']); 
}
}
}

print_r($data);

?>
```

Comment: Благодарю. Буду использовать такое решение часто. Очень удобно и наглядно

Comment: учи лучше как внизу ответ

Answer (score 2):

если учесть, что со второго массива вам по `id` надо вытащить `count`, то сначала приведите его к такому виду

```
$arr2 = array_column($arr2, 'count', 'id');
```

тогда `id` станут ключами, а `count` значениями

далее преобразуйте первый массив, пройдясь по нему и прибавляя значения второго по `id`

```
$result = array_map(function($v) use ($arr2){
                   $v['count'] += $arr2[$v['id']];
                   return $v; 
                }, $arr1);
```

а если порядок значений в массивах одинаков, и их число идентично, можно и еще проще, сразу испоьзовать map

```
$result = array_map(function($a, $b){
                    $a['count'] += $b['count'];
                    return $a; 
             }, $arr1, $arr2);
```

Comment: Благодарю за ответ на первую часть

Comment: @Pvokinsark со второй еще проще все, `array_map(function($a, $b){ return $a + $b; }, $arr1, $arr2);`